# Correct way of parsing XMP XML metadata attached to the end of a PDF file?

Tags: c#, pdf, mono, metadata, xmp

I have a PDF with some meta data in XMP XML format attached to the end. What is the correct way of parsing and using this meta data?

At the minute i have a working solution using C99, parsing each character in the file, starting at the beginning and using loops until i reach a tag im after and then recording the contents until i reach the closing tag. I can't see this as the best way of doing things.

I'm now rewriting this program using C# + [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) (not .NET) and i wonder if there is a magic framework class for this task instead of just imitating the C99 version? (Also, i can only rely on third party libraries if they don't contain any p/invoke stuff, etc.)

I'm using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) because i need this app to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe has published the [XMP specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xmp/sdk/XMPspecification.pdf). Give it a try. You need to find out what XMP schema the XML uses and parse it accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

If you can get the complete XML as a string, you can use [`XmlDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) to get the complete XML in memory for querying.

You can then use XPath with the [`XmlDocument.SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes.aspx) method in order to get to your data.